# find the eigenvalue of A ???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $10 \times 10$ matrix defined by $A=(a_{ij})$ where $(a_{ij})=1-(-1)^{i-j}$

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 
     0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \cdots & 0 &2 \\ 
     2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots &2 &0 \\
     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
      0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & \cdots &0 &2\\
      2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots &2 &0\\ 
   \end{pmatrix}$$
Now find the eigenvalue  of $A$ ???

My attempts :  i can find  the  eigenvalue of $2\times 2 $ and $3\times 3 $matrixes ..But  now  i can not able  to  find the eigenvalue of $10\times 10$ matrixes    how   can  i find ???

pliz help me

Comment: Do you mean *an* eigenvalue?  All the row sums are $10$ so $10$ is an eigenvalue.  (A vector of all ones is a corresponding right eigenvector).

Comment: None of the current answers explains an easy way of seeing all the eigenvalues. First off, the rank of $A$ is $8$. This tells us that $0$ is an eigenvalue and there's room for only two more eigenvalues, tops. Since the sum of the rows is always $10$, this means $10$ is an eigenvalue. Since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, it follows that $-10$ is an eigenvalue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide an alternate formulation, one that may be more useful in other problems but is also useful here.

Your matrix happens to be this matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \quad 2 \\ 2 \quad 0 \end{pmatrix}$, just repeated five times across and five times down. There is actually an operation to describe this, the *Kronecker product*. Look it up on Wikipedia or Wolfram Mathworld.

In particular, if $\mathbf{[1]}_5$ is the $5 \times 5$ matrix consisting of all $1$s, then the matrix that you have, is nothing but:
$\mathbf{[1]}_5 \otimes M$.

Here's the big result :

> The set  of eigenvalues of $A \otimes B$ is  formed by taking all possible products of eigenvalues of $A$ with eigenvalues of $B$.

So, the recipe is simple : find all the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{[1]}_5$, all the eigenvalues of $M$, and take products.

The point about $\mathbf{[1]_5}$ is that even though it is $5 \times 5$, there is some pattern to its characteristic polynomial, which one may derive by induction. For example, just look at square matrices of small dimensions with all $[1]_s$.

The characteristic polynomial of the $1 \times 1$ matrix $[1]$ is $x - 1$.
 For $\mathbf{[1]}_2$ it is $x(x-2)$, for $\mathbf{[1]_{3}}$ it is $x^2(x-3)$. In fact, you can prove that it is $x^{n-1}(x-n)$ for $[1]_n$.

Hence, the eigenvalues of $[1]_5$ are the roots of $x^4(x-5) = 0$ i.e. the eigenvalues are $0$ and $5$.

The eigenvalues of $M$ can be found from its characteristic polynomial, which is $x^2 - 4 = 0$ so $x = \pm 2$.

You can verify from here :  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Kronecker+product+%5B%5B%5B1,1,1,1,1%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1%5D%5D,%5B%5B0,2%5D,%5B2,0%5D%5D%5D

That the eigenvalues of matrix you want are : $0 \times 2$ , $0 \times -2$, $5 \times 2$ and $5 \times -2$, which gives the set $\{0,10,-10\}$.

Comment: thanks  a lots...this  one  is more  interesting answer

Comment: You are welcome. I love this approach a lot, and I use it a lot to answer questions about eigenvalues of matrices with these patterns.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :  What is the rank of your matrix ? What about $X=\left(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\right)$.

Comment: ya,,,,Ranks is  10   but  im not getting @Atmos  why u take  $X=\left(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\right)$.??

Comment: The rank is not $10$, that's why i suggested you to look up to find it. And maybe $AX=10 X$ ? ( maybe )

Comment: thanks   alots @Atmos  i got its

Answer (score 1):

The rank of $A$ is clearly $2$. Besides, $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ and $(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1)$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $10$ and $-10$ respectively. So, the eigenvalues are $10$ (with multiplicity $1$), $-10$ (also with multiplicity $1$) and $0$ (with multiplicity $8$).

Comment: @GitGud I've edited my answer. Thank you.